# Concatenating string to keys and values in a dict of list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict which contains lists as it's values. Let's say

```
mydict = {
    '1': ['4', '3', '8'],
    '2': ['3', '7', '5']
}
```

What I want to do is add a character to each key and a different character to each element of the list. Let's say  `mydict` should become

```
mydict = {
    '1a': ['4b', '3b', '8b'],
    '2a': ['3b', '7b', '5b']
}
```

I was able to change the keys by doing the following:

```
def m(mydict):
    return dict((k + 'a', m(v) if hasattr(v, 'keys') else v) for k,v in mydict.items())
```

But wasn't able to do it with the elements of the lists in the same function. Is there a concise way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension on the dict values will do:

```
print({k + 'a': [i + 'b' for i in v] for k, v in mydict.items()})
```

This outputs:

```
{'1a': ['4b', '3b', '8b'], '2a': ['3b', '7b', '5b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by nesting a dict comparison and a list comparison as follows

```
mydict = {
    '1': ['4', '3', '8'],
    '2': ['3', '7', '5']
}

letterdict = {
    key + 'a' : [e + 'b' for e in value]
    for key, value in mydict.items()
}

letterdict

> dict_items([('1a', ['4b', '3b', '8b']), ('2a', ['3b', '7b', '5b'])])
```